# Add a custom header per rule on Kubernetes Ingress with Traefik

Tags: kubernetes, traefik

I'm moving to `kubernetes` using `traefik` as my Ingress Controller.

I have a single backend that should respond to 3000+ websites. Depending on the host, I need to add a custom header to the request before proxy passing it to the backend.

I can use the `ingress.kubernetes.io/custom-request-headers` annotation to add a custom header to the request but it's an annotation for the whole Ingress, so I would need to create 3000+ Ingresses, one for each website.

Is there another way to do this? Creating 3000+ Ingresses is the same thing as creating one Ingress with 3000+ rules?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you need to create one Ingress object per one host, if you want different headers her host.

You can do it by Traefik:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: traeffic-custom-request-header
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/custom-request-headers: "mycustomheader: myheadervalue"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: custom.configuration.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: http-svc
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
```

Also, the same thing you can do by [Nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) Ingress Controller.

It has the support for `configuration snipper`. [Here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/examples/customization/configuration-snippets/ingress.yaml) is an example of using it to set a custom header per Ingress object:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-configuration-snippet
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      more_set_headers "Request-Id: $request_id";
spec:
  rules:
  - host: custom.configuration.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: http-svc
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
```

BTW, you can use several different ingress controllers on your cluster, so it does not need to migrate everything to only one type of Ingress.

Comment: In your example, you're setting the same header for all rules, right? What I need is to set a different custom header for each rule. I don't think I can do that because I cannot make annotations inside the rules object. That said, my only option is to create one ingress per host (each ingress with a single host rule). I've created 3000+ ingresses with a single rule each with traefik as the controller and it's working, so I'm ok for now, but I'm afraid of that because I don't know if creating so many ingresses can be a problem or not.

Comment: Yep, you are right. I for some reason read Ingress as Ingress Controller in your question:( I will update an answer.